# Is 70-80°C a safest operating temperature for PC?

Tags: cpu-temperature

I have AMD FX-8350 Octa core processor running at 4.0 Ghz stock speed on stock cooling fan. I also have ultra low end GT 610 Asus 0dB (no fan) 2GB graphics card. While gaming the CPU temperature is rising up to 61°C and GPU above 75-80°C. Ambient temperature here is 38°C. Is it safe to run pc at this temperatures? Should i need a cooling system? If yes, air or water cool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

61C is the [published maximum from AMD](http://products.amd.com/en-us/search/CPU/AMD-FX-Series/AMD-FX-8-Core-Black-Edition/FX-8350/92)... GT 610 has a [published maximum temp](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-610/specifications) of 102C.

Your GPU is running within acceptable parameters, although the CPU temp is high but barely within specifications, I would think on occasion it is exceeded. The stock cooler should be more than sufficient, but the thermal paste included is less than "optimal". I would recommend replacing it with a high quality thermal paste (this brought my CPU temp down 10-15C under load).

Assuming you are not overclocking at all, the stock cooler should be more than sufficient for the CPU and installation issues are the likely the primary cause of problems. If there is an air gap or misalignment of the cooler, if the thermal paste is not spread correctly, or other it is not seated properly, temperatures can get excessive. Do not attempt to reuse the same thermal paste, meaning do not remove the cooler and stick it back on without cleaning the CPU and cooler with isopropyl alcohol and reapplying new quality thermal paste.

Quality third-party coolers are inexpensive, and although are not required would have no negative effect, but the same rules of installation with thermal paste would apply. A water cooler setup is generally only needed for overclocking situations.

Comment: So you are saying that its ok to use air cool instead of spending money on liquid cool unless im overclocking it right? Suggest me a good air cooling system for amd 3+ .

Comment: You can use liquid cooling when not overclocking. Like I was saying below, you can still run stock speed more efficiently

Comment: @Susmith We do not make specific product recommendations here at Superuser... I would suggest going to Newegg or your favorite online computer store and find a list of compatible coolers and sort by Customer Ratings or something similar, and select a reasonably priced well reviewed/rated model. But you are correct, I do not recommend water cooling for all but overclocking, and even then only when it is pretty hard-core overclocking. I will reiterate that the stock cooler is more than sufficient when properly installed with quality thermal paste.

Answer (score 1):

70-80C is not a good range. Many motherboards actually shut down automatically if 80 is ever reached. There is no "correct" temperature but the lower the better. I personally run at about 20degrees C to 40 with a load. You will always get more performance out of a GPU or CPU the lower the temperature goes.

There is a correlation of lower temps = more performance.

Air vs liquid cooling is really up to you. It is cost vs performance at that point. Liquid cooling will be more expensive than air cooling but will also produce lower temperatures and therefore give you better performance as listed above.  Air cooling can perform decently well for most cases. It is really up to you for the cost. Do make sure in either case that you have a good thermal paste bond and keep the fans and such clean of dust.  Even liquid cooling has fans too.

If you currently have air cooled, try cleaning everything:

1. Remove all the dust with some canned air and some rags.
2. Detach the cpu cooling fan and heatsink from the CPU.
3. Clean off all old thermal paste from the cpu AND the heatsink.
4. Reapply new thermal paste. The method how you do this is up to you but one way is to apply with your finger onto the cpu surface AND the heatsink surface. Apply only a small amount like shown below, and rub around with your finger until the entire interaction surfaces are covered:

[image]

5. Latch the fan and heatsink back down.

Comment: Proper application of thermal paste seems to be more of an opinion than a factual answer these days... everyone thinks they know the best way, the reality is it doesn't matter if you use the credit card method, the finger method, or the squish method, as long as there is not excessive amounts of paste and there are no air gaps, your pretty good. :)

Comment: Sure, I agree with this. I was trying to show a picture to show approx how much so he doesn't just put globs on. The thinner the better actually (so long as it actually covered completely) as it is a layer of conduction that conducts quickly to the heatsink.  Too much will act as an insulator and not as effective of a conductor. I did update my answer to state that it is simply one method.

Comment: @eric F . Thank you. The build is brand new so its is dust free. I wil try adding good quality thermal paste.

Answer (score 0):

75C is extremely hot for a computer. What type of computer is this, and what type of load are you putting on it to cause those temps (or where are you keeping the computer, I'm an IT person, and when your client puts a bean bag around their computer to make it look nice, it causes to overheat, and then I have to deal with it. Don't do this)

I suggest getting a better cooling system. or just shutting down your computer to keep it from breaking in itself. Maybe your fan or its controller are broken? Maybe the thermometer?